# react native / iOS google maps on M1 simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps, x86-64, apple-m1

I am trying to get google maps running on the iOS simulator on an M1 chip machine.
Currently, I am running all pod installs via:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

to not get any confusion on architectures.
When I install google-maps packages following the explanation here [enter link description here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md) I always run into:

> [...]/ios/PROJECT.xcodeproj The linked library 'libPods-PROJECT.a' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.

I tried already starting in rosetta mode with the same result. Also, I tried just using pod install, but then that destroys the whole project and I cannot build anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project with xcode. Select your pods and build settings tab. Set x86_64 to`Excluded Architectures Debug`. Now run your app with xcode. If this is not working, try the same action for target app.

[image]

Target app tab:

[image]

Comment: I am installing every single package (pod) for x86_64 and I do have to exclude arch arm64 since I cannot run it in xcode on an M1 chip. Excluding now x86_64 of course cannot work. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Pods overwrites the settings in your workspace in Xcode. Add this to the end of your `Podfile` to avoid building in arm64 architecture:

```
...

    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    #add these lines below:
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
    #------

  end
end
```